# Cannot rewrite branches:git

Tags: git

i have merge the branch (old to new). After merging, when I try to sync on new branch one of framework `Opentok` is exceed the size. So I had run the below command to ignore the framework while pushing through terminal but its show the error.

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Pods/OpenTok/OpenTok.framework/OpenTok'

 Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
```

Answer (score 3):

Unstaged changes on your worktree, I guess. try stashing them so you save them and get them back later on. `git stash save 'will come back to continue working later on'`